# resolvent representation of semi-groups in stochastic process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

Let $Z$ denote the random walk in continuous time with the generator  $(\kappa+\rho)\Delta$ with respective starting point z.

Let $R_\lambda^{\kappa+\rho}(z)$ denote the related semi-group given as following. Then by resolvent representation of semi-groups we get:
$R_\lambda^{\kappa+\rho}(z)
=\int_0^\infty  \:\mathrm{d}t \: e^{-\lambda t}\:\mathbb{E}_z^Z\exp\bigg\lbrace\gamma\int_0^t \: \delta_0(Z_s) \:\mathrm{d}s \bigg\rbrace=\frac{1}{\lambda}+\gamma\bigg (\int_0^1 \:\mathrm{d}t \: e^{-\lambda t}\:p_{(\kappa+\rho)t}(z)\bigg) R_\lambda^{\kappa+\rho}(0)$,
where $p_{(\kappa+\rho)t}(z)=\mathbb{P}^{Z}_0{(Z_t=z)}=\mathbb{P}^{Z}_z{(Z_t=0)}$ is the transition probability.

The quenstion is: **how to get the expression in the last equality?** I mean, the part $R_\lambda^{\kappa+\rho}(z)
=\frac{1}{\lambda}+\gamma\bigg (\int_0^1 \:\mathrm{d}t \: e^{-\lambda t}\:p_{(\kappa+\rho)t}(z)\bigg) R_\lambda^{\kappa+\rho}(0)$.

I think the idea is to make use of the resolvent representation of semi-groups, but somehow I tried a lot but still failed to get the last equality.

Comment: Are you following any notes or textbook? Can you provide a reference?

Comment: Hi~ I am going to present the results of this paper,  http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.1512. This was in page 6 referred to the proof of Theorem 1 in this paper.